# RecyclerView ItemClickListener is not working in OnBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, textview, onitemclicklistener

how to get a particular textview's getText(string) when clicked in RecyclerView ?
I have tried like holder.itemview.setOnclickListener in OnBindViewHolder but nothing i see in log.

I got solution for this but it only works with double click. Any solution for single click ???

Please check my adapter class code below

```
public class AddressAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<AddressModel, AddressAdapter.viewHolder> {
    

    public AddressAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<AddressModel> options) {
        super(options);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final AddressModel model) {
        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.locationID.setText(String.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition()+1) );
        holder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
        holder.address.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        holder.name.setPaintFlags(holder.name.getPaintFlags() |  Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
   
         //Guys this is not works in single click only works in double click
        holder.imgDeleteLoc.setOnClickListener(v -> {
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         
            Log.d("cl",holder.getText().toString());
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.saved_locations, parent, false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }


    class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         TextView locationID,name,address;
        ImageView imgDeleteLoc;

        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            locationID=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddressIdCounter);
            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            address=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
            imgDeleteLoc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDeleteLoc);
           
        }
    }
}
```

My Inflator XML below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    style="@style/CustomCardViewStyleTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <!-- Insert UI elements -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="#2/22 Nainiyappan Garden 3rd Lane Old Washermenpet Chennai -600021"
        android:textColor="#77959292" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddressIdCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="Shaik"
        android:textColor="#77959292"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Saved Locations"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDeleteLoc"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Please anyone help to get the particular textview content when click on recyclerview.

Comment: Share your layout file `saved_locations`

Comment: yes added pls check

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call

```
holder.imgDeleteLoc.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Log.d("cl",holder.address.getText().toString());
    });
```

Comment: hmm I tried but still its not working even i didn't see any toast or log

Comment: hey it works, but not works in single click it works with double click, any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

you should not use findViewById again, you can try to get the text by either:

- `holder.address.getText()`
- `model.getAddress()`

Comment: ok fine I tried this and it works but with double click not in single click

Answer (score 0):

First update here with my code:

```js
class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         TextView locationID,name,address;
        ImageView imgDeleteLoc;

        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            locationID=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddressIdCounter);
            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            address=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
            imgDeleteLoc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDeleteLoc);
        }
    }
```

And try this:

```js
String getAddress = holder.address.getText().toString();
```

Comment: yes right but not works with single click

Answer (score 0):

Update the `ImageView` as follows or you can use `ImageButton`

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDeleteLoc"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
```

Comment: @BeginnerDev try with little bigger size, lets say 50dp height and width